# How to get data based on two collections in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

Imagine there are two collections, User and UserHistroy. I just need to find the set of Users who are having certain values in UserHistroy Collection. (like Users who had ***usage*** more than 18)

User  => {"id": **123**,"name" : "X", "type" : "regular"},  {"id": **456**,"name" : "Y", "type" : "regular"}

UserHistory => {"id":**123**, "usage" : 36, "balance" :11, "month": "SEP"}, {"id":**123**, "usage" : 20, "balance" :12, "month": "OCT"}, {"id":**123**, "usage" : 30, "balance" :32, "month": "NOV"}

I just need to prepare the aggregate function using Golang and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Answer updated yo add the condition.

You need [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Something like this:

```js
db.User.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 123
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "UserHistory",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "history"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "history": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$history",
          "as": "h",
          "cond": {
            "$gte": [
              "$$h.usage",
              18
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OShk6misBMr)

Also I've added one stage, `$match` to get the result for a given `id`. You can use this to filter or remove to get tho join from all documents into `User` collection.

After the `$lookup` I've used `$addFields` to update the field with only the objects that has value grater than 18.

Comment: Yes, but my concern was, how do I check that condition of usage 18 in this lookup.

Comment: Oh that's true, sorry. Give me a few minutes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Also if your issue has been resolver, mark answer as accepted is apreciated :)